# How to write update query for long string in Oracle using jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a query

```
String sqlQuery = 'update t1 set col1 = ? where colId = ?';
```

Table Structure:

```
t1 table
--------------
colId   |col1
--------|------
Integer |Clob
-------------
```

col1 - value can be more than 4000 characters. 
So, when I execute the query I am getting the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long
>   01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"

How to write a sql update query . i don't want stored procedures ? Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Clob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html) can be up to `2,147,483,647` characters long so it should be enough in your case, to prevent this issue instead of providing the value as a `String` literal which is limited to `4,000` characters long as you already have noticed, provide it as a nAscii stream or a `Clob`, thanks to respectively one of the methods `setAsciiStream` or thanks to the method [`setClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob-int-java.io.Reader-) of the class `PreparedStatement`.

Here is a concrete example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...

// - set the value of the input parameter to the input Reader
ps.setClob(1, new StringReader(myStringContent));
// Or setAsciiStream(1, fis);
ps.setInt(2, id);
ps.execute();
```